# Find the index of the minimum element in a subarray

Tags: c++

The function FindSubArrayMinimum is suppose to return the index of the minimum value in an array between the values (left,right). Instead of returning 1 as it should, it returns 7.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Minimum {

int *array;
int arrayLen;

public:

Minimum(int *array, int arrayLen) {
}

void swap(int &a, int &b) {
    int x;
    x = a;
    a = b;
    b = x;
}

int findMinimum(int a, int b) {
    if(a < b){
        return a;
    }else{
        return b;
    }
}

int findArrayMinimum(int a[], int arraySize) {
    int min=a[0];
    for(int i=0;i<arraySize-1;i++){
        if(a[i] < min){
            min = i;
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int findSubArrayMinimum(int a[], int arraySize, int left, int right) {
    int min = a[left];
    for(int i=left;i<right+1;i++){
        if(a[i] < min){
            cout << min << endl;
            min = i;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
int findSubArrayMinimumAndSwap(int left, int right, int swapIndex) {

}

};

int main() {

int A[5] = {47, 7, 21, -1, 11};
Minimum min(A, 5);

cout << "Minimum of 7 and 11 is " << min.findMinimum(7, 11) << endl;

int x = 5, y = 7;
min.swap(x, y);
cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << endl;

cout << "Minimum value is at position " << min.findArrayMinimum(A,5) << endl;
cout << "Minimum value between [1,2] is at position " << 
min.findSubArrayMinimum(A,5,1,2)<< endl;


return 0;
}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it won't return the minimum index. Logically speaking it should work unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes, you're missing something. You're missing a [mcve] in your question, as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. What is `findMinimum()`? What is `findArrayMinimum()`. There's a declared function called `findSubArrayMinimum()`, but the `main()` constructs some mysterious class named `Minimum`, that's nowhere to be found, and calls its method called `findSubArrayMinimum()`. Whether it's the same `findSubArrayMinimum()`, or not, is completely unclear. The question is very disorganized. You need to read stackoverflow.com's [help], and edit your question to provide a [mcve], as explained.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<arraySize-1;i++)` why are you doing this? you're stopping before the last element when you subtract 1 from `arraySize`, assuming that you have a sane value for `arraySize` i.e. the size of the array.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm not sure why I had it added there to be honest, I guess I just added it because the teacher had the same thing below (arrayLen - 1). I'm pretty new at c++ and am trying to learn as I go by studying other's code

Comment: Besides other problems in your code, think about what `min` is in both your find minimum functions. You are trying to keep track of both the value of the minimum element and the position of it in the same variable. Use this if statement instead: `if(a[i] < a[min])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all of my other functions as all the ones I have finished I have working.

It is not true. In `findArrayMinimum` the loop should be

```
for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
```

Or

```
for(int i=0;i<=arraySize-1;i++)
```

The initial value an the condition in the loop are also wrong. Should be `int min=0` and `if(a[i] < a[min])`

> Instead of returning 1 as it should, it returns 7.

`findSubArrayMinimum` is nice, except initial minimum value `int min = a[left]`, should be `int min = left` and the condition in the loop should be `if(a[i] < a[min])`.

`arraySize` is odd in `findSubArrayMinimum`, it is not used.

Your do not need the separate implementation for `findSubArray`. You can do `return findSubArrayMinimum(a, 0, arraySize - 1)` in `findSubArray`.

If you would implement the tests with arrays of 0, 1, many elements, with the left, right, middle subarrays, you would discover all bugs in your code.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is all about not re-inventing wheels.

```
#include <algorithm>

size_t findArrayMinimum(int a[], size_t arraySize) {
    // Returns index of minimum element
    return std::min_element(a, a + arraySize) - a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your findSubArrayMinumum you need min = a[i]; and not min = i; i is a index and a[i] is value.

**I suggested you:**

```
int findSubArrayMinimum(int a[], int arraySize, int left, int right) {
    int index = left;
    int min = a[left];

    for(int i=left;i<right+1;i++){
        if(a[i] < min){
            min = a[min];
            index = i;
        }
    }

    return index;
}


int index = min.findSubArrayMinimum(A,5,1,3);
cout << "Minimum value between [1,2] is at position " << index << 
". and value is: " << A[index] << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int findSubArrayMinimum(int a[], int arraySize, int left, int right) {

//The min is the index of minimum value since you are returning the index only
int min = left;
  for(int i=left;i<=right;i++){
  //since we have min = indexOfMin, then we need to compare the values
  if(a[i] <= a[min]){
      min = i;
  }
}
//remember! You are returning the index of the minmum value!
return min;
}
```

Comment: It is wrong. Cont test: int A[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; cout << findSubArrayMinimum(A, 5, 0, 3); Your function return 1 and a[1] == 2 not a minimum.

Comment: sorry. my mistake,i should compare the int "i" with min